# How to use Gnome's extensions

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I have been trying to install some Gnome extensions from the site `https://extensions.gnome.org`. I get the dialogue asking if I want to install, but after I select yes, it fails silently. This is the behavior using either Firefox or Chromium. I have checked to make sure the `Gnome Shell Integration` plugin is installed and enabled for both Chromium and Firefox.

My operating system in Ubuntu 12.10, and my version of Gnome is 3.6.3.1. I have made sure (using `sudo apt-get update`) that everything is up-to-date. I have tried restarting, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Try installing `gnome-tweak-tool` and see whether the extensions appear there

Comment: Already done. They do not. There is literally nothing happening after I confirm I want to install them.

Answer (score 0):

Try do manually download them and put them in this folder:

> ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

Be sure that the version you download match with the version of gnome you have installed, and be sure that the folder of the extension have this name style:

> "name extension"@"email creator"

Sometimes when you manually download an extension the folder have some extra info about the version like:

> unite@hardpixel.eu.v20.shell-extension

so you need to remove the text after the email,like this:

> unite@hardpixel.eu

or gnome will not see the extension.